# How to search between messages between two time ranges?

Tags: slack, slack-api, datetimerangefield

I have a channel in slack, to which a CI tool sends notification. The CI tool sends notification for failure for every operation and there is no way to filter it out. But I know that important notifications come from 12 AM to 2 AM. Is there a way that I can apply a filter daily on that channel between two time intervals ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can call the API method [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history), which will return messages from a channel. By settings the parameters `oldest` and `latest` accordingly you will only get messages from a specified timeframe.

Note that those parameters are provided as absolute timestamps (e.g. `1234567890.123456`), so you need to calculate them for the current day.